# lmer random intercept effects estimated for each time step

Tags: r, lme4

I would like to estimate a random effect for Subject within each Day. In the data set, not every Subject is observed every Day, and therefore, I should not have an estimated effect for each Subject in each Day. I want to estimate a separate variance parameter (10 total, 1 for each Day) and distribution of Subjects within each Day (independent between time steps), to evaluate the change in the among Subject variability over time. Is this possible with lmer?

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)

set.seed(1)
sleep = sample_n(sleepstudy, size=500, replace=T)
sleep$Days = as.factor(sleep$Days)

table(sleep$Days, sleep$Subject)

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Days/Subject), sleep)

summary(fm1)
ranef(fm1)
```

Comment: Possibly a better question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you would benefit more from using a Latent Growth Curve model as opposed to a Mixed Model. I believe the growth function in lavaan would best suit you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look.